# Drawing Cumulative Distribution Function in r

Tags: r

I have the following pdf,

```
f(x)=2(1-x)^2;  2=>x>1
```

Now i have to plot the `cdf` of the random variable in `r`.

```
#cumulative distribution function

Fx <- function(x){
          (2/3) * (x^3-3*x^2+3*x-1)
      }

R <- runif(100,1,2)

cum_prob <- Fx(R) # determining cumulative probability
```

But i don't know which command should i use to draw the `cdf` .

`hist()` & `barplot()` are not appropriate for cdf. Because as far i know plotting a cdf, it requires the values of random variable in X-axis, and cumulative probability in Y-axis.

Also my variable is continuous.

Comment: Will a simple `plot(x,y)` not be enough for you?

Comment: You need to `integrate` or `cumsum` a PDF in order to get a CDF. (This is basic probability and not a proper question for SO. If you do not know what you are doing then use a venue where tutoring or homework help  is part of the program.)

Comment: @Floris Thank you. The command is plot(R,cum_prob)

Comment: @DWin Is there any way to calculate the cdf in `r`? I tried this : `fx<-function(x)2*(x-1)^2`                                               `integrate(fx,1,x)`

Comment: Please read the help page more carefully. The third argument to integrate is the (numeric) upper limit and you have given it an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to the code in the comment:

```
fx <- function(x)2*(x-1)^2 
integrate(fx,1,2)
#------------
0.6666667 with absolute error < 7.4e-15
plot(seq(1,2,by=0.01), cumsum(fx(seq(1,2,by=0.01))*0.01 ), type="l" )
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you have multiplied `0.01` here:`cumsum(fx(seq(1,2,by=0.01))*0.01` ?

Comment: Because integral(f(x)) = cumsum( f(x)*d(x) ) ... Newton and Liebnitz and all that jazz.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

Define density:

```
f <- function(x) (2*(1-x)^2)*(1<x & x<=2)
```

Plot density:

```
plot(f,0,3)
```

Plot CDF:

```
plot(Vectorize(function(X)integrate(f,0,X)$value),0,3,add=TRUE)
```

Note: 0 and 3 are limits of x axis in the plots; you can change them. Also note your density is not normalized.

[image]